# Blinking Cursor at login

Tags: boot, 12.10

Sometimes after my laptop boots up there is a blinking cursor on the top left side of the screen, I can still login via Unity, after login everything works but the cursor is still there blinking, it messes up the launcher bar somewhat as well, has anyone else seen/experienced this? This seemed to start in 12.10.

Comment: Like after you login and load unity you get a blinking cursor? Can you take a screenshot or a pic? Some more info about your harware would help also: graphics card the most important one.

Comment: @BrunoPereira I sure can! Next time it happens I will take a screenshot, and yes after I login the cursor continues to blink (it actually begins blinking at the login screen) however I'm still able to login/do everything. Usually it can be solved by a reboot or two...and my graphics card is a AMD Radeon 6490M Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem too. When this happens, after logging in, I can't switch to tty1 with (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) because of corrupt graphics. Logging out and in again, seems to fix this problem. My graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 6570.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here since fresh install of 12.10 64bits. My card is AMD Radeon HD 5450 / catalyst 12.6.
I had no problem on my previous 12.04.

After logging graphically, there is a black blinking cursor overlaid on X11, and this cursor is captured when doing a full-screen screenshot. [image: http://tinypic.com/r/16a77h3/6]

The black cursor is the input of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> tty : if I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, I do not switch to the usual black console but the console text is overlayed on top of X11.

Comment: Seems like the logging in and out tip from koulamaras worked for me :), still kind of annoying but beats having to reboot each time :).

Comment: I confirm : logging in and out works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the blinking cursor and no login after an upgrade from 18.04 to 19.04.

My 18.04 was working fine and I had wifi connected and working and all drivers installed. I remembered my username and password as well.

After the upgrade, I rebooted to find a blinking cursor and nothing else... I fixed it though.

First, I used the CTRL+ALT+F2 key combination (Press the 3 together at the same time) to enter tty2

I logged in by typing my username without the computer name (just your username, not 'username@compername') and then my password.

Next, I updated my computer with 'sudo apt update' then 'sudo apt dist-upgrade'.

Last I entered 'sudo startx' and I logged in fine. I restarted and it started fine.

I hope this helps!